# Exo Platform Remove Address Port 8080

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, port

We've started to use Exo Platform Community 4.3 in our company.

The only issue so far is that to access the platform the link is:

**http://ipaddress:8080**

We've used DNS configurations for us to be able to have:

**http://intranet.company.com:8080**

The issue is that, we are not able to remove the mandatory **:8080** (port) from the address link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've changed It to port 80 on home_eXo/conf/server.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 is setup in home_eXo/conf/server.xml file, And you can not remove it, If you want to change this port you need to update this file with new port.

Comment: Hi there, I know that :/ But which port should I use for it not to show on the url?